# java -split xpath-string into chunks (seperator [.+] ???)

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I got several XPath expressions which I have to split.
Example

```
NODEA[NODEA1/NODEA11][NODEA2/NODEA21][NODEA3/NODEA31]/NODEB
```

The stuff in square brackets could be there multiplie times.
I need an array that should look like

```
NODEA[NODEA1/NODEA11]
NODEA[NODEA2/NODEA21]
NODEA[NODEA3/NODEA31]
NODEA/NODEB
```

I do not have any clue how a regex could look like.
I guess I have to start to read from right to left.
Everything in square backets except the aktual square bracket hat to be deleted?
Maybe I am wrong and there is a better solution.

As I do not often work with regex any help is appreciated.

Many thanks
Regards
Mario

Comment: Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively. We do not write code for you, you are expected to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first.

Comment: Hi Jim,sorry, but I do not understand. What is wrong with my question?

Comment: Hi Jim,sorry. But I do not have any idea how to start fixing my problem?
As I am no expert in regex I wrote that "any help is appreciated". I did not expect any final code.

Regards Mario

Comment: I tried

`String[] split = str.split("(?<=])");`

but I am getting the result:
`NODEA[NODEA1/NODEA11]
[NODEA2/NODEA21]
[NODEA3/NODEA31]
/NODEB`

which is near to my requirement.

Comment: I tried:
`String[] split = str.split("(?<=])");`

But I am getting the result:
`NODEA[NODEA1/NODEA11]`
`[NODEA2/NODEA21]`
`[NODEA3/NODEA31]`

`/NODEB`

which is near to my requirement. Could anybody pls. help?

Answer (score 0):

For your given example, you could get the different parts by for example using [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

[`NODEA|\[[^]]+]|\/NODEB`](https://regex101.com/r/1Z3ejd/1)

**That would match**

- `NODEA`
- `|` Or
- `\[[^]]+]` Match for example `[NODEA1/NODEA11]` by matching an opening `[`, then match not an `]` and then match an `]`
- `|` Or
- `NODEB`

You could loop through the matches and add those parts to a collection like an ArrayList.

Then remove and capture the first entry `String nodeA` of that list which will be `NODEA` leaving the rest as is.

For the rest of the parts in the collection you want to prepend the value of `nodeA`. You could then loop through the collection and prepend `nodeA` to all the entries in the collection:

```
String regex = "NODEA|\\[[^]]+]|\\/NODEB";
String string = "NODEA[NODEA1/NODEA11][NODEA2/NODEA21][NODEA3/NODEA31]/NODEB";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();

while (matcher.find()) {
    ar.add(matcher.group(0));
}

String nodeA = ar.remove(0);

for (int i = 0; i < ar.size(); i++) {
    ar.set(i, nodeA + ar.get(i));
}
```

[Demo Java](http://rextester.com/ZXH94707)